# Calculate difference of days between dates in different rows, based on consecutive value of a column, for each customer_id

Tags: postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table like this one, that shows payments from each client, for different dates:

```
|  stream_datetime | customer_id | order_status | rn |
|:----------------:|:-----------:|:------------:|:--:|
| 04/06/20 11:19AM |      1      |   completed  |  1 |
| 05/06/20 10:54AM |      1      |   completed  |  2 |
| 06/06/20 10:59AM |      1      |   completed  |  3 |
| 08/06/20 09:27AM |      2      |    failed    |  1 |
| 09/06/20 11:02AM |      2      |    failed    |  2 |
| 01/11/20 05:59PM |      3      |   completed  |  1 |
| 02/11/20 05:59PM |      3      |   completed  |  2 |
| 03/11/20 10:01AM |      3      |   cancelled  |  3 |
| 04/11/20 09:20AM |      3      |   completed  |  4 |
| 05/11/20 10:25AM |      3      |   completed  |  5 |
| 01/13/20 03:29PM |      4      |   completed  |  1 |
| 02/13/20 03:29PM |      4      |   completed  |  2 |
| 03/13/20 03:29PM |      4      |   cancelled  |  3 |
| 04/13/20 03:29PM |      4      |   completed  |  4 |
| 05/13/20 03:29PM |      4      |   completed  |  5 |
| 06/13/20 03:29PM |      4      |   completed  |  6 |
| 07/13/20 03:29PM |      4      |   completed  |  7 |
| 08/13/20 03:29PM |      4      |   cancelled  |  8 |
| 06/20/20 03:29PM |      5      |    failed    |  1 |
| 07/20/20 03:29PM |      5      |   completed  |  2 |
| 08/20/20 03:29PM |      5      |   completed  |  3 |
| 09/20/20 03:29PM |      5      |    failed    |  4 |
| 10/20/20 03:29PM |      5      |   completed  |  5 |
```

I want to calculate the difference of days a client `canceled` his plan.

The challenge here is the fact that the client can cancel more than one time, so client `4` must
be counted as a `churned` client two times, but client `3` would be counted as a `churned` client
only one time.

I want to consider only clients that has an `order_status = completed` followed by (not necessarily in the next month) an `order_status = cancelled`.

I want too to create a column called `purchase_day` that keeps the day of the payment.

Obs.: the column `rn` means row number for the specific client.

---

**EDITED:**
Sorry. I made some mistakes and writing the question.

Maybe the `order_status = cancelled` come first than `order_status = completed`. This is due a mistake in the business, but it can happen. If this happen, so we cannot consider as a churned client.

So this is my expected result (now this is ok):

```
|   purchase_day   | customer_id | lifetime|
|:----------------:|:-----------:|:-------:|
| 01/11/20 05:59PM |      3      |   60    |
| 01/13/20 03:29PM |      4      |   60    |
| 04/13/20 03:29PM |      4      |   122   |
```

As you can see:

- client `1` never cancelled (so he doesn't need to be in the result)
- client `2` never cancelled (so he doesn't need to be in the result)
- client `3` cancelled one time (his lifetime is equal 60 days)
- client `4` cancelled two times (one lifetime of 60 days and another lifetime of 122 days)
- client `5` never cancelled (so he doesn't need to be in the result)

Comment: I'm seeing customer_id = 1 cancelled?  Is `purchase_day` the date of the first record or payment for that `customer`?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. User `1` never canceled. I fixed it. `purchase_day` is the first record of the payment, but if he already cancelled once, then there will be another "first" puchase_day, like those for the user `4`.

Comment: Thanks - one additional Q: I see customer 2 never has a `order_status` of "complete", yet the `purchase_day` is 04/06/20, although the first `stream_datetime` for 5 is 06/20/20 and the `purchase_day` is 07/20/20.  How should that be set?

Comment: Sorry. I made some mistakes when writting the question. I'm editing right now.   
Better to keep the result only for clients that have cancelled once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, had to do this in three steps:

1. To mark which records we want to keep (first record for each customer, records where the status changed)
2. To get the prior row's `stream_datetime` and calculate the the difference between
3. Select only the rows where the `order_status` was 'cancelled'.

```
SELECT
  customer_id
 ,purchase_day
 ,lifetime
FROM
(
  SELECT
    customer_id
   ,order_status
   ,LAG(stream_datetime) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY stream_datetime) AS purchase_day
   ,CAST(stream_datetime AS DATE) - LAG(CAST(stream_datetime AS DATE)) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY stream_datetime) AS lifetime
  FROM
    (
      SELECT
        customer_id
       ,stream_datetime
       ,order_status
       ,CASE
          WHEN customer_id <> LAG(customer_id,1,-1) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY stream_datetime) THEN 'Y'
          WHEN order_status <> LAG(order_status,1,'') OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY stream_datetime) THEN 'Y'
          ELSE 'N'
        END AS change_ind
      FROM
        Payment
      WHERE
        order_status IN ('completed','cancelled')  
    ) payment_summary
  WHERE
    change_ind = 'Y'
) payment_change
WHERE
  order_status = 'cancelled'
    AND purchase_day IS NOT NULL
```

Results in:

```
customer_id     purchase_day            lifetime
3               2020-01-11T17:59:00Z    60
4               2020-01-13T15:29:00Z    60
4               2020-04-13T15:29:00Z    122
```

You can test with this [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/12ffd/6).

I'd recommend running the subqueries by themselves to get a feel for how each step works and so you can be confident in the results.

> Your query worked pretty well!. But I forgot to tell something: maybe
> the order_status = cancelled come first than order_status = completed.
> This is due a mistake in the business, but it can happen. If this
> happen, so we cannot consider as a churned client.

Ok, this is easy enough to fix given how things are set up.  If the cancel has been entered erroneously, `purchase_day` will be NULL (we already ignore instances with two consecutive statuses), so we can just change the final `WHERE` to:

```
WHERE
  order_status = 'cancelled'
    AND purchase_day IS NOT NULL
```

Updated [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a9a7b/3) for you to test.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will test it.

Comment: Your query worked pretty well!. But I forgot to tell something: maybe the `order_status = cancelled` come first than `order_status = completed`. This is due a mistake in the business, but it can happen. If this happen, so we cannot consider as a `churned` client.

Comment: @igorkf Not a difficult fix - see updated answer and Fiddle

Comment: Thank you very much! You helped me a lot : )

Comment: @igorkf Glad to help